# fixing a div at the top of the page with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible, to fix a div bar at the top of the page even when scrolling, and 
still be able to fully see the next div?

The bar div is given a height of 15vh and the other divs are set to 85, so when You see the first view of the page divs #bar and #one are displayed.

I would like that after scrolling down that divs #bar and #two are seen. I tried everything: giving margin, padding, position relative, absolute, adding to #one top: 15vh;. Tried also putting div on #one and #two divs.. made all combinations..

This is the code I have so far that is the closest to what I mean and can't find how to go futher

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#bar {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 15vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85vh;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 85vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">


  <div id="bar"></div>

  <div id="one"></div>

  <div id="two"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Depending on requirements and browser support, you can use `position: sticky` or `position: fixed` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I can see the ``#bar`` div is actually fixed at the top part. I dont understand what you are trying to achive in. Can you elavorate

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-top:15vh;` to  `#one` to create/add the part which is hidden behind the fixed navbar

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#bar {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 15vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top:15vh;
  height: 85vh;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 85vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">


  <div id="bar"></div>

  <div id="one"></div>

  <div id="two"></div>

</div>
```